# The message could not be processed because the action 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/SCT' is invalid or unrecognized.

Tags: wcf, wif, saml

Trying to setup STS with WCF Claims Aware. I am getting this message on the client:

> Server Error in '/ClientWebsite' Application. The message could not be
>   processed because the action
>   'http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/SCT' is invalid
>   or unrecognized.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem with `WIF 4.5` and `ADFS 2.0`. I solved it by disabling the security context on the binding:

```
binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue and had to turn off security context on WCF bindings (Like what Andy Williams suggested). You need to turn them off on the bindings in both the client and the service.

Here's the config file if your WCF is IIS-hosted:

```
<ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
    <binding>
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
```

See this post:
http://stack247.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/an-unsecured-or-incorrectly-secured-fault-was-received-from-the-other-party/